# how can i use a viewmodel to access a function from another fragement

Tags: android, android-view, viewmodel

i have two fragments that i want them to communicate using viewmodel architecture fragment A has a function that checks the color of the cardview if there are changed no i want to access that function using viewmodel accessing it normally causes null exceptions. its acradview that when pressed it changes the color, how can i achieve that using viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

use activity scope ViewModel, fragments below a single Activity are shared ViewModel, your fragments can observe ViewModel's change and do something you want

Comment: thanks but am a newbie how do i perform that brother @so

Comment: welcome, but you need learn this refer at first https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: okay brother i know get it fragment A will set the function then fragment b will get the function on the view model but the function i have doesnt pass any parameter

Comment: brother forexample here MutableLiveData<Object> what object am i supposed to pass cause my function accepts no parameters its a bolean function

Comment: brother you should change your mind that you cannot directly hold a reference of another fragment such as FragmentA in FragmentB, as said before, you already observe the viewmodel in both of  FragmentA/FragmentB, you should do whatever you want in the observer in any of FragmentA/FragmentB that holds the ViewModel